# Trying to retrieve json informations in a function with Fetch API and then trying to use them in another function

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch-api

I need to fetch some informations from a URL (which contains informations in JSON) about several objects.
So i wrote:

```
static fetchObj(){
fetch("http://localhost:1337/objects")
.then(callback => { 
return callback.json();
})
.then(data => {
console.log(data);
});
}
```

Here I can retrieve the things I need and console them for being sure.

Then I have to use these data in another function that finds these objects by ID:

```
static fetchObjById(id) {
      MyClass.fetchObj()
      .then(
          for(var i=0; i<data.id.length; i++){
            if(data[i].id == id)
              console.log("found");
            else
              console.log("not found");
          }
   }
```

But it doesn't work at all.. I tried several methods but nothing.. I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Don't just `log` the `data` in `fetchObj` but return it - and also `return` the promise from the function. In `fetchObjById` you need to pass a callback function that takes `data` as a parameter to `then` - passing a loop is not valid syntax

Comment: You syntax is wrong. The argument passed to `then()` must be a function.

Comment: You should embrace your loop like `MyClass.fetchObj().then(data => {for....}`

Comment: Now i wrote this:

 `static fetchObj(){
  return fetch("http://localhost:1337/objects")
      .then(callback => { 
       return callback.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
       return data;
      });
    }

    static fetctObjById(id) {
      MyClass.fetchObj()
      .then( data => {
          data.forEach(d => {
            if(d.id == id){
              console.log("found: "+ d.name);
            }
            else
              console.log("not found");
          })
        })
    }`

It seems to work, but i don't know if it's correct. I added some return..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also a way to find the id.

```js
var id = 4;
function fetchObjById(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].id === id) {
            console.log('found');
            break;
        }
    }
}

var myData;
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => myData = data)
  .then(() => fetchObjById(myData));
```

Answer (score 1):

`then()` expects a function. You can access the Promise's result data through this function's single parameter, which is easily accomplished with an arrow function.

Also, I would recommend you to ditch the explicit for loop and look into declarative programming. Similarly to `then()`, calling `forEach()` on an array gives you access to each element with an arrow function. To me, this is much more readable.

Finally, the `console.log` call could be simplified a little by first declaring what the print message should be (using a ternary operator), then calling `console.log` once with that message.

```
const fetchObjById = (id) => {
  MyClass.fetchObj()
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(d => {
          const message = d.id === id
            ? 'found'
            : 'not found';
          console.log(message);
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i commented under the first comment :) i tried to add the foreach statement to eliminate the other temp variable i :)

Comment: Code without comments is useless. Your answer is much more helpful to everybody if you explain what you did and why you did it.

Comment: @FelixKling I added some comments.